# Node failure on windows 7

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, msbuild, node-gyp

==============================

## **SOLVED:** switched from node 4.0.0 to 0.12.7. Node v4.0.0 seems to be pretty raw yet

I've read many articles, they didn't help me. Any workarounds?

I've installed Visual Studio Express 2013 on my Windows 7, and did `set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013`. But I still get the following errors related to `socket.io` dependency while `npm install`:

```
error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)' : function template 
error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type [
error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' [
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' [
error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier [
..............
gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
```

*Full log*

```
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(263): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)' : function template has already been defined [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(256) : see declaration of '_NanEnsureLocal'
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2039: 'FreeCallback' : is not a member of 'node' [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FreeCallback' [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'callback' : undeclared identifier [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'hint' : undeclared identifier [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(672): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\VBakhmatiuk\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffer.h(43): could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
          C:\Users\VBakhmatiuk\.node-gyp\4.0.0\include\node\node_buffer.h(31): or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *, const char *, uint32_t)'
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(676): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local(const v8::Local<v8::Object> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object>'
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C2039: 'Use' : is not a member of 'node::Buffer' [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found [PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this exact problem on Ubuntu and Mac. Rolling back to socket.io version 1.3.5 should works.
The command for this on Mac and Ubuntu is: npm install socket.io@1.3.5.

I do not know what the Window's command is.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

- install visual studio community 15
- execute the  msbuild prompt (visual studio tools access menu)
- add the MsBuild program to the path env: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`
- execute `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`
- add the directory to a short location (sometimes fails because a limit of 260 characters in windows os systems)

seems that exist a failure with the npm-debug system and node 4 io integration. If you are trying to use a generator try if the code runs already
if you are using a generator

Comment: NOTE: disable temporary any antivirus action i.e. AVG to install visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution isn't clear from the accepted answer.

I was having the exact same issue on Win7, and I had to completely uninstall Node 4.0.0 and reinstall 0.12.7 from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/

After that, `npm install` worked perfectly.

Comment: I did, but it's not immediately obvious, and it's not very detailed. The solution should really be in an answer, not in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing the appropriate Visual Studio and npm config, you may also need to delete the 'node_modules' directory to get 'npm install' to work again.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
Go to System-Properties (run: systempropertiesadvanced.exe), in Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.

Still on the System variables, click 'New', add "NODE_PATH" with value "C:\nodejs64\node_modules", and click OK.

click 'New' again, add "NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK" with value "1", and click OK.

Click OK of all dialogs close.

Restart your machine, so explore and cmd will get the fresh set of variables.
```